# Nginx rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"

Tags: php, nginx, web

I implement web server on nginx with Php framework without any index.html, web page works fine, but some script doesnt working, it says "500 internal server error"

Here's the server log

> 2016/11/16 11:08:38 [error] 2551#0: *738 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /kelontong/getKelontong HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:09:20 [error] 2551#0: *746 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /kelontong/getKelontong HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:14:47 [error] 5500#0: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /department/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:14:48 [error] 5500#0: *6 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /department/getdepartment HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:18:56 [error] 5518#0: *4 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /department/getdepartment HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:18:56 [error] 5520#0: *8 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /department/getdepartment HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"
>
> 2016/11/16 11:21:35 [error] 5534#0: *3 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 27.131.251.6, server: www.foreverstore.id, request: "GET /department/getdepartment HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.70.86"

And here's my nginx host config file

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;

 root /bwi/foreverstore.id;
 index index.html index.htm index.php;


 server_name www.foreverstore.id ;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/foreverstore.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/foreverstore.key;

 location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    #  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
 }

 location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
 }

 error_page 404 /404.html;
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
  }
}
```

if you guys know how to solve this problem, i will be thankfull to you 
cheers.

Comment: I think the reason is because once `$uri` and `$uri/` fails, it redirects to `/index.html` and then it runs through the `try_files` again and fails at `$uri` and `$uri/` then redirects to `/index.html`. You get the picture... Try changing `/index.html` to `/index.php` so that if it fails at `$uri` and `$uri/`, it will default to your `\.php$` block

Comment: i also have try that method, but still it didnt solve my problem, it just redirect to my homepage, that i want is to see my engine is working like my other server (apache2) 

like https://example.com/departmen/GetDepartment ( it show my engine on apache2 )
but on nginx, it just error/redirect to homepage

Comment: If it redirects to your homepage, then your initial problem of a redirect loop is solved and so this is a solution to your issue. Anything over and above you'll need to configure on your backend or ask a new question with more details describing what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried, what you're expecting to happen, and what is actually happening.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I think the try_files line should look like:

`try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;`

Comment: i already using that script, but still it didnt work. i didnt use any html file, just php framewrok

Answer (score -1):

Since you ain't using any html files as you stated, change your root location block:

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

You have to include a try files as well in your php block so when it FAILS it goes there instead of seeking a redirect:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
  fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Since you declared: `error_page 404 /404.html;` you can also add the 404 location:

```
    location = /404.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
            internal;
    }
```

This should stop those ugly redirect loops.