# NGINX Error; 1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"

Tags: node.js, nginx

```
2021/02/23 18:50:45 [error] 3476#3476: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 192.168.0.50, server: _, request: "GET /search HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.94", referrer: "http://192.168.0.94/"
```

I am trying to make a website using node.js as I want to implement other apps in the future. I am able to get sub-directories on my PC, but when I try to use on anything, I get this error.

Here's my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/personalsite.error.log;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index search.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ^~ /search/ {
        alias /var/www/html/views/;
    }

    location ^~ /results/ {
        alias /var/www/html/views/;
    }

}
```

And my app.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

// Init App
const app = express();

// Load View Engine
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js')));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Web Routes
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    res.render('search.html');
});

app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    res.render('results.html');
});

app.get('/found', (req, res) => {
    res.render('found.html');
});

app.get('/player', (req, res) => {
    res.render('player.html');
});

// Start Server
app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

If you know why this is the issue that would help me massivley, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
```

Read more on [Nginx rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624153/nginx-rewrite-or-internal-redirection-cycle-while-internally-redirecting-to-in)